# Run Pusher on Background Thread iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, pusher

I am rendering html pages on main thread. Hence I cannot run Pusher on the same thread as the main thread as it keeps dropping messages.

Is there any way of running always running Pusher on a background thread in iOS?

I have tried Grand Central Dispatch but it does not work as after initialising, Pusher comes back on the main thread.

Thank you

this is what I have so far.

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            client = [PTPusher pusherWithKey:@"xxxxxxxx" delegate:self encrypted:NO];

            client.reconnectAutomatically = YES;
            client.reconnectDelay = 1; // defaults to 5 seconds

            [client connect];

            PTPusherChannel *channel = [client subscribeToChannelNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Company_%@", [Settings sharedSettings].company.companyID]];

            [channel bindToEventNamed:@"ServicePrint" handleWithBlock:^(PTPusherEvent *channelEvent) {
                NSLog(@"[pusher event] Received event %@", channelEvent);
                //do some work here
            }];

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Add code here to update the UI/send notifications based on the
            // results of the background processing
        });
    });
```

Comment: What's the message it's 'dropping'?

Comment: new notifications that come in. It is dropping some of them while the main thread is being used.

Comment: Do you try to use some NSOperation in specially created for this task NSOperationQueue?

Comment: added some source code for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using it on the Main thread and dropped a lot of other functionality on the main thread. Seems to be working fine so far.